# NodeJS & ExpressJS: How to store user info in session after logged in?

Tags: node.js, session, express

I did lot of research but I am new on this, I couldn't find something concrete.
When a user is logged-in I would like to store some user info in session like Name, Profile_picture, Id, so I can use it for example in the navigation bar.

How can I achieve this?

For example in PHP is too easy just adding this line of code the information stays in what ever page you visit (before session expire)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an express-session: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sessions

and then store the session like this:

```
let session = require("express-session");

app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    }
}));
```

This session will be stored during your visit on the webpage. If you want to set values to the cookie, simply request the cookie in a request and set somekind of value:

```
router.route("/login")
    .post(function(req, res) {

        req.session.Auth = req.body.user // => user values?
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use express-session or cookie-session(https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session)

If you use cookie session & you made any change session variable or in server side, then **no need to restart server**.

It will help you to increase your development speed, because you, no need to restart server.

```
app.use(cookieSession({
 name: 'session',
 keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}))

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // Update views 
  req.session.views = (req.session.views || 0) + 1

  // Write response 
  res.end(req.session.views + ' views')
})
```